# How can I get consecutive nowrap spans to wrap as separate elements?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a block of text where I want to group words up as pairs so the two words do not break. There is an unintended consequence where when you have two `<span></span>` tags in a row he whole line turns into nowrap.

Example: `<div><span style="white-space: nowrap;">...</span><span style="white-space: nowrap;">...</span></div>`

**Code below is baseline**: The result will wrap at any `" "`(space) or `"-"` that the container has.
(NOTE: **This example is meant to be on a responsive web-page.**)

```
<div class="block-of-text" style="max-width: 550px">
  One-two Buckle-my-shoe, Three-four Shut-the-door,
  Five-six Pick-up-sticks, Seven-eight Lay-them-straight,
  Nine-ten Do-it-again.
</div>
```

The Result of the Base line will look something like this.

```
|--------------- My Web Page ---------------| (550px)
|                                           |
|  One-two Buckle-my-shoe, Three-four Shut- |
|  the-door, Five-six Pick-up-sticks, Seven-|
|  eight Lay-them-straight, Nine-ten Do-it- |
|  again.                                   |
|                                           |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

I want to make sure any hyphenated word surrounded by `<span class="nowrap">...</span>` stays on the same line.
Below is my attempt. (NOTE: I have One-two not surrounded by nowrap on purpose to show how it will not be included in the result.)

```
<style>
  .nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
</style>

<div class="block-of-text" style="max-width: 550px">
  One-two <span class="nowrap">Buckle-my-shoe, </span>
  <span class="nowrap">Three-four </span><span class="nowrap">Shut-the-door, </span>
  <span class="nowrap">Five-six </span><span class="nowrap">Pick-up-sticks, </span>
  <span class="nowrap">Seven-eight </span><span class="nowrap">Lay-them-straight, </span>
  <span class="nowrap">Nine-ten </span><span class="nowrap">Do-it-again.</span>
</div>
```

My unintended result looks something like this and is NOT what I want. The `<span>` tags are acting as one giant `nowrap`.

```
|--------------- My Web Page ---------------| (550px)
|                                           |
|  One-two                                  |
|  Buckle-my-shoe, Three-four Shut-the-door, Five-six Pick-up-sticks, Seven-eight Lay-them-straight, Nine-ten Do-it-again.
|                                           |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

**What I want to have happen**:

```
|--------------- My Web Page ---------------| (550px)
|                                           |
|  One-two Buckle-my-shoe, Three-four       |
|  Shut-the-door, Five-six Pick-up-sticks,  |
|  Seven-eight Lay-them-straight, Nine-ten  |
|  Do-it-again.                             |
|                                           |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

### **SOLUTION**

Thanks to everyone and especially *@Kravimir* for helping find the solution:

It works when adding style `display: inline-block;`, while having all spans on the same line, and adding spacing with `&nbsp;` *inside* the span.

```
<style>
  .nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>

<div class="block-of-text" style="max-width: 550px; border: solid 1px red">
  One-two&nbsp;<span class="nowrap">Buckle-my-shoe,&nbsp;</span><span class="nowrap">Three-four&nbsp;</span><span class="nowrap">Shut-the-door,&nbsp;</span><span class="nowrap">Five-six&nbsp;</span><span class="nowrap">Pick-up-sticks,&nbsp;</span><span class="nowrap">Seven-eight&nbsp;</span><span class="nowrap">Lay-them-straight,&nbsp;</span><span class="nowrap">Nine-ten&nbsp;</span><span class="nowrap">Do-it-again.</span>
</div>
```

*Additional info on solution*: If you put `" "`(space) or `&nbsp;` outside of the span it does not work as intended or you get 2 spaces between spans. Also the whitespace at the end of a line is not observed when the `<span>` tag is on a new line.

TLDR; Solution was edited in above.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/debabrata/p5y7dk4v/1/. I created this fiddle. It seems to be working. Isn't it?

Comment: Thank you @DebabrataPatra
They are still linking if the `<span>` is on the same line as the second `<span>`
It does seem to work if you put everything on its own line and then run the fiddle again.

Comment: It is still not working as intended and my ACTUAL real website is using Angular 7 with bootstrap and I am serving it normally and using chrome and firefox to see the compilation. I see all the spans have the correct css are closed, and nothing seems to be interfering with them from the "computed" tab. I am stumped even though the JS fiddle is able to work as intended when "seperating lines only"

Comment: As @isherwood answers below, you really need to get the spaces out of the spans. One other alternative is forget the spans and use [non-breaking hyphens](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm)

Comment: How are the spans being added? If it's you doing it manually you can just put the spaces _between_ the spans instead of within them. If they're automatically added (somehow by magic) you should be able to adjust that to, again, put the space between rather than within the spans. If your goal is "to make sure any hyphenated word..." and the spans are your attempt, can you simply type it in differently? Why not? I think these considerations are important to solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`.

```css
  span.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="block-of-text" style="max-width: 550px">
  One-two <span class="nowrap">Buckle-my-shoe,</span>
  <span class="nowrap">Three-four</span> <span class="nowrap">Shut-the-door,</span>
  <span class="nowrap">Five-six</span> <span class="nowrap">Pick-up-sticks,</span>
  <span class="nowrap">Seven-eight</span> <span class="nowrap">Lay-them-straight,</span>
  <span class="nowrap">Nine-ten</span> <span class="nowrap">Do-it-again.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting Note: by doing this that you will get (depending no the width) some places where the words will visually run together, like "Five-sixPick-up-sticks", even though _copy/paste_ will include the space.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't change the HTML. That doesn't happen when there is white-space between all of the `<span>` elements. (I'll edit it now to adjust that.) Alternatively, a small right margin could be added to each.

Comment: SO this 100% works IF you put every span on the same line and also add a &nbsp; after each text and remove the spaces between each span.  Angular also understand this and it is functioning correctly on it's server.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because, without spaces between the spans, they act as characters in a single word. You need to put spaces between the spans, not inside them.

```css
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-of-text" style="max-width: 550px; border: 1px solid red">
  One-two <span class="nowrap">Buckle-my-shoe,</span> <span class="nowrap">Three-four</span> <span class="nowrap">Shut-the-door,</span> <span class="nowrap">Five-six</span> <span class="nowrap">Pick-up-sticks,</span> <span class="nowrap">Seven-eight</span> <span class="nowrap">Lay-them-straight,</span> <span class="nowrap">Nine-ten</span> <span class="nowrap">Do-it-again.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing `span` so

```css
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-of-text" style="max-width: 550px">
  One-two <span class="nowrap">Buckle-my-shoe, </span>
  <span class="nowrap">Three-four </span><span class="nowrap">Shut-the-door, </span>
  <span class="nowrap">Five-six </span><span class="nowrap">Pick-up-sticks, </span>
  <span class="nowrap">Seven-eight </span><span class="nowrap">Lay-them-straight, </span>
  <span class="nowrap">Nine-ten </span><span class="nowrap">Do-it-again.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out the </span>, it was intended to be close in my question yet does not solve my issue... I edited it in my question yet I am still running into the same issue and my ACTUAL real website code is still showing the same issue even after quadruple checking if all span's are closed.

Comment: @JamesEssex check once your white-space: nowrap; css is not overriding by other css in your ACTUAL real website

Comment: It is still not working as intended and my ACTUAL real website is using Angular 7 with bootstrap and I am serving it normally and using chrome and firefox to see the compilation. I see all the spans have the correct css are closed, and nothing seems to be interfering with them from the "computed" tab. I am stumped even though the JS fiddle is able to work as intended when "seperating lines only"